# Storing python class instances to iterate over and process, but keeping instances separate per session

Tags: python, class

I have 2 different classes A, B
I am trying to build an API which reads a file and based on the lines it can either:

```
1. create corresponding class instances when it sees lines likes
"create A <nameA1>", "create A <nameA2>", "create B <nameB1>" etc.
2. append line to existing instances when it sees lines like "append hello A <nameA1>", "append heyy B <nameB1>"
3. relate A and B when it sees lines like "relate A <nameA2> B <nameB1>"
```

After completing log file parsing, i need to then iterate over these instances of A and B and find the relations and build one final instance of another object C (lets ignore C for now)

I tried using the a class variable to store instances as they get created. and used an iterator metaclass to iterate over instances. It all worked fine and well, until I start testing it out back to back. The class variable is not getting updated and it stores the list of instances from the previous file i uploaded to the api as well. Is there an alternate solution to this? I have been trying to dig up something but so far to no luck.

Comment: You are going to have to provide a [mcve]. Honestly, it isn't clear to me what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: You seem to have quite a compound problem, it may help you to break down this task into smaller steps, as many of those steps already have suitable answers available on this site.  If you run into specific troubles, edit this question or create a new to ask about them.